AsyncStream with multiples observers in Swift
I'm trying to create a generic async stream which exposes filtered events:
final class MyComponent {
    private let receivedMessageDataStream = AsyncStream.makeStream(of: Data.self)
    
    func commandStream<C: Decodable>() -> AsyncStream<C> {
        AsyncStream<C> { continuation in
            Task {
                for await data in receivedMessageDataStream.stream {
                    guard let commandWrapper = try? decoder.decode(CommandWrapper.self, from: data),
                          commandWrapper.commandType == String(describing: C.self) else {
                        continue
                    }
                    
                    guard let command = try? decoder.decode(C.self, from: commandWrapper.commandData) else {
                        continue
                    }
                    
                    continuation.yield(command)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // When receiving new data the receivedMessageDataStream is updated
    // like:
    // receivedMessageDataStream.continuation.yield(newDataReceived)
}

And this is working fine:
Task {
    for await event: Event1 in service.commandStream() {
        print(">>> 1) Update receive", event)
    }
}

but as soon as I launch a second observer:
Task {
    for await event: Event1 in service.commandStream() {
        print(">>> 2) Update receive", event)
    }
}

Just the last one receives the update. I know I can acomplish this with Combine, using PassthroughSubject (which allow multiple observers). Is it possible to have the same behavior with Swift Concurrency?
In the previous case, the same Event1 is used for filtering, the event is received by one or the other. But when having observers with different event types, like:
Task {
    for await event: Event1 in service.commandStream() {
        ...
    }
}

Task {
    for await event: Event2 in service.commandStream() {
        ...
    }
}

Suppose that we sent an Event2, for some reason, the first time the Event2 is consumed by the first observer, which is ignored and continued (as the type doesn't match), and then the second event2 that gets sent is then processed by the second observer.
So, in other words in the commandStream in the following line:
for await data in receivedMessageDataStream.stream {}
I was expecting that no matter how many times commandStream is called, each one should receive its continuation and loop through the receivedMessageDataStream.stream (but looks like only the last observer keeps reacting to the stream).
Thanks in advance.

What you're looking for is called a broadcast, or sometimes multicast or shared, stream, and it's not currently available. https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-async-algorithms-proposal-broadcast-previously-shared/61210/46

Unrelated to the question at hand, I would make a few suggestions re commandStream: First, I would capture the Task and then add a continuation.onTermination closure which cancels it if the state was .cancelled. Second, I would make sure that you add a continuation.finish() in case the for-await-in loop ever completes or is canceled, so that if it  does finish looping, the AsyncStream is finished, too. Third, you might want to make MyComponent a Sendable type: If you change the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting to “Complete”, it will warn you of the issue.

“looks like only the last observer keeps reacting to the stream” … I think it’s worse than that; I find that it’s not entirely consistent regarding which gets the value.
